# Синхронизировать канвас с анимацией

Tags: javascript, css3, анимация, canvas, css-animation

В каждом фрейме отрисовки (`requestAnimationFrame`) в центре канваса рисуется круг. Размер канваса анимируется. В Хроме и FF круг немного дрожит, а в IE он заметно толстеет перед перерисовкой - т. е. браузер сначала растягивает имеющуюся картинку, а потом заменяет её новой. Почему так происходит и как исправить?

[image: скринвидео в gif]

Насколько я представляю, если я делаю что-то в requestAnimationFrame, то содержимое страницы вообще не должно перерисовываться, пока я не закончу. Соответственно, на момент отрисовки должна отрисоваться сразу новая версия. Но в IE сценарий не такой?

https://jsfiddle.net/3wLroppt/

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  
  var width = canvas.clientWidth, height = canvas.clientHeight;
  
  canvas.width = width * 2;
  canvas.height = height * 2;
  
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  var cx = width, cy = height, r = height;
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

requestAnimationFrame(function frame() {
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  animation: w-100-200 .5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes w-100-200 {
    0% { width: 200px; }
   50% { width: 400px; }
  100% { width: 200px; }
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Надо впилить анимацию в js

Comment: @Darth, как? Или ты предлагаешь css'ную анимацию выпилить?

Comment: Ну ясен васин. Вы же сами написали - сначала кружок рисуете, а потом css его растягивает. Вставьте вместо requestAnimationfFrame setInterval c таймаутом побольше, чтобы было видно нагляднее

Comment: @Darth, но ведь он не должен растягиваться?

Comment: @Darth таймаут можете и здесь `animation: w-100-200 .5s linear infinite;` изменить, зачем в `js`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Почему не должен? CSS пофиг, что у вас там в канвасе внутри. Даже больше - ему пофиг, что это канвас. Он просто берет и растягивает картинку, как обычный jpeg. А вы чего хотели - неясно

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan хмм, хорошая мысль..

Comment: Я попробовал поставить в css `steps(5), а в анимации - setInterval(draw, 100); , поидее тогда они должны более менее в такт работать, но почему то вообще ничего не происходит)

Comment: @Darth, потому что если я делаю что-то в requestAnimationFrame, то содержимое страницы вообще не должно перерисовываться, пока я не закончу. Соответственно, на момент отрисовки должна отрисоваться сразу новая версия. Но что-то идёт не так...

Comment: Что то идёт не так **после** отрисовки, перед следующей отрисовкой

Answer (score 3):

Нашел ответ, правда на `IE` пока не тестировал, у меня `linux`)))

Как я и подозревал дело было в том что анимация с высотой и шириной по умолчанию происходит так:

Например у вас ширина должна с `200px` расшириться до `400px` в определенном промежутке времени (`$t`), и расчет происходит так - к ширине добавляется один пиксель в `(400-200) / $t` времени.И кода размер ширины контейнера нечетное количество пикселей то центр круга рисуется на один пиксель вправо (по оси `x`) (201/2 пиксель шириной для него будет 101px), и это приводит к непредусмотренной анимации (дрожанию) круга внутри контейнера.

Эту проблему я решил свойством [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function), у него есть значение `steps`.

там можно задать шаг анимации и у нас поскольку от `200 - 400` будет 100 2-пиксельных шагов прописываем в нем 100 `animation-timing-function:  steps(100);`

И вот что у меня получилось:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="animation" width="200" height="200">
    
</canvas>
<style>
    
    canvas {
        outline: 1px dotted red;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;        
    }
    .animation{
        animation: w-100-200 .5s linear infinite;
        animation-timing-function:  steps(100);
    }
    @keyframes w-100-200 {
        0% { width: 200px; }
        50% { width: 400px; }
        100% { width: 200px; }
    }
    
</style>
<script>
    let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    function draw() {     
  
        var width = canvas.clientWidth, height = canvas.clientHeight;
  
        canvas.width = width * 2;
        canvas.height = height * 2;
  
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
        var cx = width, cy = height, r = height;
  
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
        
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(function frame() {
 draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
        canvas.className += " animation";
    });
</script>
```

А это пример от автора но время я поставил `5s` что бы наглядно было видно непредусмотренная анимация черного круга.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="animation" width="200" height="200">
    
</canvas>
<style>
    
    canvas {
        outline: 1px dotted red;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;        
    }
    .animation{
        animation: w-100-200 .5s linear infinite;
        /*animation-timing-function:  steps(100);*/
    }
    @keyframes w-100-200 {
        0% { width: 200px; }
        50% { width: 400px; }
        100% { width: 200px; }
    }
    
</style>
<script>
    let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    function draw() {     
  
        var width = canvas.clientWidth, height = canvas.clientHeight;
  
        canvas.width = width * 2;
        canvas.height = height * 2;
  
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
        var cx = width, cy = height, r = height;
  
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
        
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(function frame() {
 draw();
        requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    });
    $(window).load(function(){
        canvas.className += " animation";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Про дрожание из-за нечётности всё верно, но в IE проблема не в этом. https://jsfiddle.net/3wLroppt/2/ - тут в Хроме всё шикарно, а в IE - нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да я сказал что в IE не проверял, LINUX стоит у меня и не могу тестировать пока. Но на какой версии IE вы тестируете?

Comment: В IE11. У Edge та же проблема - сегодня посмотрел.

Comment: @Qwertiy Понятно, вечером посмотрю на IE

Comment: И косяк гораздо заметнее проявляется на быстрых анимациях, чем на 5-секундных, поэтому в вопросе и стоит полсекунды.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685411/178988 - более локализованный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Вы же сами написали - браузер сначала рисует кружок с помощью js,а css его тем временем растягивает.

```js
let start = Date.now();
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const height = canvas.clientHeight;

function draw() {
  let dt = Date.now() - start;
  var side = Math.pow(-1, ~~(dt/500));
  var delta_width = 200 * (dt%500)/500;
  
  width = canvas.width = ((side>0)?200:400) + side * delta_width;    
  prev = Date.now();      
  var cx = width/2, cy = height, r = height;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, 100, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

setInterval(draw, 54);
```

```css
canvas {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Сегодня что то у меня всё отправляется раньше времени.. ща доделаю) а то гармошка что-то криво работает

Comment: В IE не парсится возведение в степень из ES2016.

Comment: Хоспаде) Math.pow

Comment: Да я в курсе, но сниппет-то не запускается...

Comment: Обновил, стало лучше?

Comment: Да... Но как-то мне не нравится это решение...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685411/178988 - более локализованный вопрос