# IE выполняет requestAnimationFrame после отрисовки, а не до

Tags: javascript, анимация

## Кратко:

В IE11 и Edge div в сниппете после клика становится зелёным, хотя не должен.

## Подробно:

Рассмотрим следующую ситуацию: есть `div` чёрного цвета.
При клике по нему мы запрашиваем `requestAnimationFrame` и меняем цвет на зелёный.
В коллбеке `requestAnimationFrame` меняем цвет на красный.

Для наглядности в `requestAnimationFrame` добавлен цикл, вешающий браузер на 3 секунды, а на div повешена css-анимация, чтобы было ясно, что браузер повис.

Ожидаемое поведение (которое наблюдается в Chrome и Firefox):

1. Есть черный div
2. Происходит click
3. Цвет формально меняется на зелёный, но перерисовки нет
4. Без перерисовки вызывается коллбек `requestAnimationFrame`
5. Браузер зависает на 3 секунды с **чёрным** div'ом на экране
6. Цвет div'а меняется на красный
7. Происходи перерисовка c **красным** div'ом

Однако, IE и Edge на шаге 5 показывают **зелёный** div. Насколько я понимаю, такое поведение некорректно, поскольку браузер обязан дождаться выполнения кода из `requestAnimationFrame` и только потом выполнить отрисовку на экране.

Как сделать, чтобы промежуточное состояние не отрисовывалось?

Вариант не изменять состояние без `requestAnimationFrame` не подходит, поскольку в реальной задаче (см. [вопрос о canvas'е](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684823/178988)) эти изменения вызваны css-анимацией, а не скриптом. Кроме того, проблема проявляется даже при двух вложенных `requestAnimationFrame`.

https://jsfiddle.net/8Ljn14ee/2/

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('click', function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    var t = new Date;
    t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 3);
    while (new Date < t);
    div.style.background = 'red';
  });

  div.style.background = 'green';
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  animation: w-100-200 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes w-100-200 {
    0% { width: 200px; }
   50% { width: 400px; }
  100% { width: 200px; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/44835860/4928642)

Comment: а почему ты говоришь, что зеленого не должно было быть? Мне кажется как раз поведение EDGE вполне логично

Comment: @Grundy, у меня же в 7 пунктах расписано, почему. Потому что вызвав requestAnimationFrame я говорю браузеру: погоди рисовать, я хочу _перед_ отрисовкой что-то сделать. А он берёт и всё равно рисует до вызова моего кода.

Comment: не не не, с чего ты взял, что _вызвав requestAnimationFrame я говорю браузеру: погоди рисовать, я хочу перед отрисовкой что-то сделать._?

Comment: @Grundy, а можешь ссылкой на спецификацию показать, что это не так?

Comment: А можешь ссылкой на спецификацию показать, что это так? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, что-то я там вообще не вижу, где описывается, когда именно браузер должен выполнять перерисовку...

Comment: Вообще, как я понял: вызов _requestAnimationFrame_ просто говорит, что когда ты будешь перерисовывать, то выполнить коллбэк, а уж когда браузер решит перерисоваться - прям сейчас же или по выходу из функции - это уж сам браузер решает

Comment: @Grundy оформите Ваш коментарий как ответ

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, вроде это не ответ. К тому же, кажется, в том виде, как написано, это утверждение неверно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну конечно же нужно переформулировать, но вцелом это и является ответом. requestAnimationFrame это лишь функция коллбек, которая отработает в момент когда браузер скажет что "сейчас удобно", и никоим образом не превентит саму анимацию