# Синхронизировать прокрутку двух блоков в IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, прокрутка

Я хочу синхронизировать прокрутку двух div'ов и написал код, подписывающийся на событие `scroll` и обновляющий `scrollTop` второго div'а. В Хроме всё отлично, в FF тоже выглядит нормально (хотя я не так уверен в идеальности, как с хромом).

А вот в IE 11 и Edge всё плохо. 
Во время прокрутки он отрисовывает промежуточное состояние, в котором только у одного div'а обновлён `scrollTop`:

> [image: screenshot]

https://jsfiddle.net/mchf10n4/7/

```js
var last = 0;

document.body.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
  var st = event.target.scrollTop;
  
  if (st !== last) {
    last = st;
    
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    
    for (var q=0; q<divs.length; ++q) {
      if (divs[q] !== event.target) {
        divs[q].scrollTop = st;
      }
    }
  }
}, true);
```

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  direction: ltr;
}

div:first-child {
  direction: rtl;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 10000px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0, white 29px, black 30px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Связанный вопрос: [IE выполняет requestAnimationFrame после отрисовки, а не до](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685411/178988).

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/47874179/4928642)

Comment: В FF57 заметно смещение в процессе. В том блоке который является ведомым отображается меньше полосок чем в ведущем ;) При остановки, все ок. UPD Это заметно было, когда в другой вкладке радио в html5 болтало.

Comment: @Visman, вот я тоже что-то такое заметил, но в большинстве случаев всё съедобно. А вот в IE совсем жесть творится... Не знаешь, как для кого-нибудь из них поправить? Только БЕЗ замены scroll на wheel.